# how to detect callout at MKannotationView?

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, mkannotationview, callouts

As we know that annView(annotation view) has left and right CalloutAccessoryView, but why annotation view doesnt have a callout outlet? because I want to make a event that will be called if Annview.callout has been clicked. or is there anything code to do that without customize Callout?

so we have annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView
and we have annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView

why we do not have annView.Callout?

Comment: check this out.
Detect tap on title of callout  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469539/detect-tap-on-title-of-callout/13495795#13495795

Answer (score 1):

Hee,

you can user the MKMapView delegate method:

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

you can check in that method wich location has been clicked with an if or switch statement.

Maby thats what you needed?

Comment: yea I know it, but there is no problem, the problem is why annView don't have annview.callout? so We can customize it easily, such as [annView.callout setgesture...]

Comment: I've found this link few days ago on SO. http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/ 
Maby that helps you out?

Comment: I want to detect the tap at callout not the accessories button.