# Detect tap on title of callout

Tags: ios, cocoa, mkmapview, tap, callout

how do I detect a tap on the **title** of a callout of a annotation? I already have a right callout accessory and a left one, but I want to detect if a user taps on the title (which is in the center on the callout).

If this is not possible, how do I disable hiding the callout if I tap on the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's little late to the answer your question but I'm dealing with same kind of problem recently and make my solution by my self with trial and error.
maybe I can help someone who dealing with same problem.

you can also use some custom annotation and callout view classes, there are many example out there.
but, there is a another simple way to solve this problem without use the complex foreign classes.

problem definition:
I want to be able to trigger some method just by touching in callout view.
I don't want to use right or left accesory buttons.
but when I touched callout view, view will disapear immediately.

short explanation of  solution:
simply we use custom "MKPinAnnotationView" with "hittest" to detect touches in callout view.

you can also find github project link at the end of the post.

touchableCallOutsViewController.h

```
//
//  touchableCallOutsViewController.h
//  touchableCallOuts
//
//  Created by yasin turkoglu on 20.11.2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 yasin turkoglu. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@class myCustomPinAnnotationClass;

@interface touchableCallOutsViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    MKMapView *myMapView;
    int pinCounter;
    myCustomPinAnnotationClass *myAnnotation;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D selectedPinCoordinate;
    int selectedPinNumber;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) MKMapView *myMapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) myCustomPinAnnotationClass *myAnnotation;
@end
```

touchableCallOutsViewController.m

```
//
//  touchableCallOutsViewController.m
//  touchableCallOuts
//
//  Created by yasin turkoglu on 20.11.2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 yasin turkoglu. All rights reserved.
//

#import "touchableCallOutsViewController.h"
#import "myCustomPinAnnotationClass.h"

@interface touchableCallOutsViewController ()

@end



@implementation touchableCallOutsViewController

@synthesize myMapView;
@synthesize myAnnotation;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //first we create mapview and add pin annotation

    myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    myMapView.delegate = self;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0,0},{1.0,1.0}};
    region.center.latitude = 41.036651; //user defined
    region.center.longitude = 28.983870;//user defined
    [myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:myMapView];

    //we define long press recognizer for 2 seconds and add our map view to add new pin when you press 2 seconds on map view
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lngPrs = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleMyLongPress:)];
    lngPrs.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
    [myMapView addGestureRecognizer:lngPrs];

    pinCounter = 1; //this variable hold pin numbers and increment 1 when new pin added.

    myAnnotation = [[myCustomPinAnnotationClass alloc]initWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pin %i",pinCounter] description:@"touch here to see pin coordinates" pinNum:pinCounter coordinate:region.center];
    [myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

}

- (void)handleMyLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    }else{
        //when we press more than 2 seconds on map view UILongPressGestureRecognizer triggered this method and call our custom MKPinAnnotationView class and add annotation.
        CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:myMapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [myMapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:myMapView];
        pinCounter++;
        myAnnotation = [[myCustomPinAnnotationClass alloc]initWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pin %i",pinCounter] description:@"touch here to see pin coordinates" pinNum:pinCounter coordinate:touchMapCoordinate];
        [myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //when new annotation added by us, new annotation property will set here
    static NSString *identifier = @"myPins";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[myCustomPinAnnotationClass class]]) {
        myCustomPinAnnotationClass *annotationView = (myCustomPinAnnotationClass *) [self.myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[myCustomPinAnnotationClass alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        myAnnotation = (myCustomPinAnnotationClass *)annotation;

        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;       
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        [annotationView setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        return annotationView;

    }    
    return nil;

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{

    //if you select any annotation to show their callout sellected annotation pin number and coordinate setted and call findcallot method    
    myAnnotation = (myCustomPinAnnotationClass *)view.annotation;
    selectedPinCoordinate = myAnnotation.coordinate;
    selectedPinNumber = myAnnotation.pinNum;
    [self findCallOut:myMapView];
}


- (void)findCallOut:(UIView *)node
{
    //this method dig our mapview with for loop until find callout view class named "UICalloutView"

    if([node isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UICalloutView") class]]){

        //this method trigered together with callout open animation.

        //in UICalloutView we have callout bubble image
        //we dig it with for loop to find this image height
        float buubleHeight = 0.0;
        for(UIImageView *bubbleComponents in node.subviews){
            //when we find callout bubble image take height to set our touchable area height
            buubleHeight = bubbleComponents.frame.size.height;
            break;
        }



        //this method triger with callout open animation as I said before
        //ant this bouncing open animation distort actual size of callout view
        //so when this happens we also get transform value of callout view and make proportion to find exact sizes.
        CGFloat nodeTransformRatio = node.transform.a;
        CGFloat calculatedWidth = roundf(node.frame.size.width / nodeTransformRatio);
        CGFloat calculatedHeight = roundf(buubleHeight / nodeTransformRatio);

        //now create a new UIView and sized according to callout view.
        UIView *touchableView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight)];
        touchableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        //we add new single tap gesture recognizer to triger desired method when users touching to the callout
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
        [touchableView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        //and finaly we add this newly created view in callout view to receive touches.
        [node addSubview:touchableView];

    }else{
        //loop self until find a "UICalloutView"
        for(UIView *child in node.subviews){
            [self findCallOut:child];
        }
    }
}

- (void)doSomething
{
    //this method call allert view our preseted variables when users touch callout view.
    UIAlertView *alertHolder = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You're touched the Pin %i CallOut",selectedPinNumber] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lat : %f\nlong : %f",selectedPinCoordinate.latitude,selectedPinCoordinate.longitude] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
    [alertHolder show];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

myCustomPinAnnotationClass.h

```
//
//  myCustomPinAnnotationClass.h
//  touchableCallOuts
//
//  Created by yasin turkoglu on 20.11.2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 yasin turkoglu. All rights reserved.
//

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface myCustomPinAnnotationClass : MKPinAnnotationView <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_description;
    int _pinNum;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
}

@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int pinNum;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)header description:(NSString*)description pinNum:(int)pinNum coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

myCustomPinAnnotationClass.m

```
//
//  myCustomPinAnnotationClass.m
//  touchableCallOuts
//
//  Created by yasin turkoglu on 20.11.2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 yasin turkoglu. All rights reserved.
//

#import "myCustomPinAnnotationClass.h"

@implementation myCustomPinAnnotationClass

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize description = _description;
@synthesize pinNum = _pinNum;
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;


- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)header description:(NSString*)description pinNum:(int)pinNum coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = [header copy];
        _description = [description copy];
        _pinNum = pinNum;
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    _coordinate = newCoordinate;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return _name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return _description;
}

- (int)tag {
    return _pinNum;
}

-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    //test touched point in map view
    //when hit test return nil callout close immediately by default
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    // if hittest return nil test touch point 
    if (hitView == nil){
        //dig view to find custom touchable view lately added by us
        for(UIView *firstView in self.subviews){
            if([firstView isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UICalloutView") class]]){
                for(UIView *touchableView in firstView.subviews){
                    if([touchableView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){ //this is our touchable view class
                        //define touchable area 
                        CGRect touchableArea = CGRectMake(firstView.frame.origin.x, firstView.frame.origin.y, touchableView.frame.size.width, touchableView.frame.size.height);
                        //test touch point if in touchable area
                        if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchableArea, point)){
                            //if touch point is in touchable area return touchable view as a touched view
                            hitView = touchableView;
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
    return hitView;
}

@end
```

Here you can download complete project listing with source code https://github.com/ytur/touchableCallOutsForIOSMaps

Comment: Hello @ytur I have the same problem with my custom callout view. I've implemented `hitTest:withEvent:`, but `[super hitTest:withEvent:]` never return `nil`. When I tap on callout view - it disappears, but when I tap on button on callout view - it did not. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is full my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449775/custom-map-callout-view-hides-on-tap