# Remove selected annotation from mapView by double click

Tags: ios, mkannotation

I need help regarding removing annotation by double click.

Once I click on any existing annotation on my map, how do I differentiate which annotation/pin selected (double click)?

or any other suggested/common way to delete pins from mapView?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

double tap gesture recognizer is reserved by map kit framework to zooming in map view by default, but you can suppress that by using "hittest" in custom "MKPinAnnotationView" class.

I prepeared an example to show how to make callout touchable in map view with "hittest".
you can achieve this problem with the same way as I can do for callouts.
[Detect tap on title of callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469539/detect-tap-on-title-of-callout/13495795#13495795)